# tikz input/includestandalone using axis mostly yields Missing/Extra {}

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, standalone, matlab2tikz

Im trying to include several graphics with `\includestandalone` (or `\input` if necessary). Neither my own simple `tikzpicture` as `standalone` with `axis` are able to compile nor the ones I create e.g. with matlab2tikz. Simple `standalone` `tikzpicture` with e.g. `circuittikz` work just fine. Simple `\input` of non-standalone `tikzpicture` dont work either, but Id like to use standalone.
Im using a derivat of KOMA-script (`tudscr` at CTAN), but the issues are similar.

With `tudscrbook` the error yields `Missing }...` and `Extra {...` around `\end{axis}`. With `scrartcl` it says `Undefiend control sequence. \end{axis}`.

But the really weird thing is that simplier `tikzpictures` compile just fine and I have not figured out what's the difference between them.
The first code is the main file, followed by an `standalone` example not working, and one simplier working (both created with matlab2tikz). Using `scrartcl` the first one yields `Undefined control sequence. \end{axis}`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

%\input{data.tex}
\includestandalone{data1}

\end{document}
```

```latex
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=20.667in,
height=1.756in,
at={(3.467in,11.31in)},
scale only axis,
unbounded coords=jump,
xmin=738356.606597222,
xmax=738356.609375,
xtick={738356.606597222,738356.606944444,738356.607291667,738356.607638889,738356.607986111,738356.608333333,738356.608680556,738356.609027778,738356.609375},
xticklabels={{14:33:30.000},{14:34:00.000},{14:34:30.000},{14:35:00.000},{14:35:30.000},{14:36:00.000},{14:36:30.000},{14:37:00.000},{14:37:30.000}},
scaled x ticks=false,
ymin=0,
ymax=8,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={$\text{Strom I}_\text{A}\text{C in A}$},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, line width=2.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
738356.606942882    0.8\\
738356.606954734    0.8\\
738356.606966053    0.8\\
738356.606977604    0.8\\
738356.606989225    0.8\\
738356.607000729    0.8\\
738356.607290313    6.4\\
738356.607301667    6.4\\
738356.60731338 6.4\\
738356.607326157    6.4\\
738356.607336389    6.4\\
738356.607347963    6.4\\
738356.609095648    6.5\\
738356.609107222    6.5\\
738356.609118796    6.5\\
738356.60913037 6.5\\
738356.609142083    6.5\\
738356.609153542    6.5\\
738356.609165185    6.5\\
738356.60917669 6.5\\
738356.609188252    6.5\\
738356.609201227    6.5\\
738356.609211412    6.5\\
738356.609222975    6.5\\
738356.60923456 1.1\\
738356.609246123    1.1\\
738356.609257674    1.1\\
738356.609269398    1.1\\
};
%\addlegendentry{A}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

```latex
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.521in,
height=3.566in,
at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=4,
ymin=0,
ymax=100,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   10\\
2   100\\
3   1\\
4   50\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to `_` within the legend ode label. In the example given this should have been clear due to the mathmode. But the issue even appears when used without mathmode in label or legend. Probably due to the `axis`-environment in the tex-file one should always use backslash before the underscore `\_`.